# About c# struct memory/serialization overhead

Tags: c#

My code is like this:

```
[Serializable]
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential,Pack=1)]
struct Foo
{
    public byte Bar;            
    public Foo(byte b){Bar=b;}
}
public static void Main (string[] args)
{
    Foo[] arr = new Foo[1000];
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        arr[i]=new Foo(42);            
    }
    var fmt = new BinaryFormatter();
    using(FileStream f= File.Create("test.bin")){
        fmt.Serialize(f,arr);
    }
    Console.WriteLine (new FileInfo("test.bin").Length);
}
```

### The result bin file is 10095 bytes big. Why do my `Foo` structs eat so many bytes? What's the 9 bytes per struct overhead all about?

PS:
 I'm writing a lookup library for Chinese characters (it's about infos for circa 70,000 characters), for which db4o or other embeddable databases (like sqlite) are kind of bloat. I thought to store all information in pure string format,which is most memory friendly, but less flexible. I'd like to keep infos in lists and store them as binary serialization into an archive, I've chosen the DotNetZip for the archiving. But the serialization overhead is an unexpected obstacle. A better serialization solution would be good, otherwise I've to save infos in plain string format and parse it by hard-coding.

Comment: Part of it can be the serialization overhead.

Comment: If 10KB is relevant, you're probably approaching this problem the wrong way.

Comment: If you're looking at optimizing the serialization speed and size, have a look at google protocol buffers.

Comment: It's not about 10kb thing, It's just a sample, in my real app, is about 100s or even 1000s of thousand objects, I found out, that each struct object will have a 9 to 12 bytes overhead, which is unbearably big.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not the Foo structure that is so "big", but instead what you're observing is the overhead of the binary serialization format itself.  This format contains a header, information to describe the object graph, information that describes the array, strings that describe type and assembly information, etc.  That is to say it contains enough information for `BinaryFormatter.Deserialize` to give you back an array of Foo as you would expect.

For more information, here is the spec that describes the format in detail: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc236844(PROT.10).aspx

Edit based on your updated question:

If you desire to simply write the contents of the structures to the stream, this can easily be accomplished in an unsafe context (this code is based off of your example).

Using a small array to write out each Foo:

```
unsafe 
{
    byte[] data = new byte[sizeof(Foo)];

    fixed (Foo* ptr = arr)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; ++i)
        {
            Marshal.Copy((IntPtr)ptr + i, data, 0, data.Length);
            f.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

Or using a single large-enough array to write out all Foos:

```
unsafe 
{
    byte[] data = new byte[sizeof(Foo) * arr.Length];

    fixed (Foo* ptr = arr)
    {
        Marshal.Copy((IntPtr)ptr, data, 0, data.Length);
        f.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }
}
```

Based on your example, this would write out 1000 bytes with a value of 42 each.

However, this approach has a few drawbacks.  If you're familiar with writing out structures in a language like C, some of these should be obvious:

- If you read the data on a machine with a different endianness than the one you used to write the data, you will not get the desired results.  You would need to define an expected byte order and handle conversion to-and-from this order yourself.
- Foo cannot contain fields that are reference types.  That means you would need to use a length field + fixed-size buffer of char instead of System.String; that can be a real pain.
- If Foo contains pointer types or IntPtr/UIntPtr, then the size of the structure may differ between machine architectures.  You would want to avoid using these types if at all possible.
- You would need to apply your own versioning scheme so that you can have some level of confidence that the data being read back in matches the expected structure definition.  Any changes to the layout of the structure would require a new versioning.

*BinaryFormatter* solves these problems for you, but incurs the space overhead you've observed while doing so.  It is designed to exchange data between machines in a safe manner.  If you do not wish to use *BinaryFormatter*, then you will need to either define your own file format and handle the reading and writing of this format yourself or use a third-party serialization library that best suits your needs (I'll leave the research of such libraries up to you).

Comment: Thanks. I've thought about byte arrays, but in my project there will be strings and lists/arrays with different length involved, the structs will not be exclusive value types containers. Therefore, I'd rather implement it in a parsing-formatting way than memory chunk copying, to minimize the memory and storage consumption

Answer (score 1):

If you want to measure how much memory is consumed you can use such code instead:

```
long nTotalMem1 = System.GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
Foo[] arr = new Foo[1000];
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    arr[i] = new Foo(42);
}
long nTotalMem2 = System.GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
Console.WriteLine("Memory consumption: " + (nTotalMem2 - nTotalMem1) + " bytes");
```

Spoiler: 1012 bytes. :)

Edit: maybe more reliable way is using `Marshal.SizeOf` method:

```
Console.WriteLine("Size of one instance: " + Marshal.SizeOf(arr[0]) + " bytes");
```

This returned 1 byte result for me, and when adding another field to the struct it returned 2 bytes so it looks pretty reliable.

Comment: why my result is 4096? It's just ununderstandably weird

Comment: @Need weird indeed.... post the full code of the method where you have that code and I'll try to see. (You can edit your original question)

Comment: @Shadow: I just copied your code. I guess the GC thing is just unreliable. I've run your code on both mono and wine .net 2.0 (sorry, at the moment, i don't have the approach to windows). The results got weirder and weirder. On mono, is at first 4096, then it turned to 16384 bytes, on wine, it's unbelievable -4028 !!

Comment: @Need sorry, maybe it's just for Windows I really don't know. I'll edit with another option. See my edit now. :)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I guess the structs definitely shouldn't eat so much memory. But the serialization overhead is still left unsolved, I've tried protobuf.net, which is even worse than the built-in one, when string or other arbitrary types are involved.

Comment: @Need what's your final goal? What will you do with the struct? Why you need it serialized for?

Comment: I've added my goal on the Question post. I really wish you or other nice people could help out of this dilemma thing. :)

Comment: @Need I fear you can't escape the serialization overhead.. "save infos in plain string format and parse it by hard-coding" is your best bet.